# About a sum over primes

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, summation, analytic-number-theory

Let $f: \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow [0, \infty)$ be a decreasing function. So
$$\sum_{p\ prime}f(p) $$
converges if, and only if
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{f(n)}{\log_e(n)}$$
converges.

I should use the Chebyshev's Theorem
$$(\log_e(2) - o(1))\dfrac{x}{\log_e(x)} < \pi(x) < (2\log_e(2) + o(1))\dfrac{x}{log_e(x)}$$
but i don't know how.

Maybe i can use this corollary
$$(1 - o(1))\dfrac{nlog_e(n)}{2\log_e(2)} < p_n < (1 + o(1))\dfrac{n\log_e(n)}{\log_e(2)} $$
where $p_n$ is the n-th prime.

Comment: Do you know summation by parts?

Comment: Yes, i know summation by parts.

Comment: Try writing $\sum_p f(p)$ using summation by parts with $\pi(x)$; then use the inequalities you wrote down for $\pi(x)$ and reverse the summation by parts.

Comment: Sorry, i can't see how i can do this. Can you show me the first step?

Comment: Following the notation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts#Method take for the first series take $a_n = f(n)$ and $b_n = 1$ if $n$ is prime, $b_n=0$ otherwise, for the second series take $a_n=f(n)$ and $b_n=1/\log n$, conclude from $\sum_{n\le x} 1/\log n\sim x/\log x$, Chebyshev's theorem and the non-negativity of $a_n-a_{n+1}$.

Comment: wow, now i understand, thanks Greg and Reuns \o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\pi (x)$ be the number of primes less than $x.$ Let $P(x)$ be the set of primes less than $x.$

Extend the domain of $f$ to $[1,\infty)$ such that $f$ is continuous and decreasing.

It is easily shown that the Prime Number Theorem $1=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac {\pi (x)\ln x}{x}$ is equivalent to $\pi(x)\sim li(x)=\int_2^x \frac {1}{\ln t}dt\,,$ that is, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\pi (x)/li(x)=1.$ And then it is easy to show that if $f:[2,\infty)\to\Bbb R $ is continuous & monotonic and if $f(x)=O(x^k)$ as $x\to \infty$ for some $k>0$ then $\sum_{p\in P(x)}f(p)\sim \int_2^x\frac {f(t)}{\ln t} dt.$

Now with $g(x)=\frac {f(x)}{\ln x},$ if $f:[2,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ is continuous & decreasing then $g :[2,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ is continuous & decreasing, and an elementary calculus result (Integral Test) is that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}g(n)$ converges iff $\int_2^{\infty}g(t)dt$ converges.

Comment: A particular case is $\sum_{p\in P(x)}\ln p\sim x.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer Daniel.